# Scrolling takes forever, horizontally

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two tables, that depend upon eachother.
So when one is scrolled, the `onScroll` event updates the other.
But scrolling horizontally with my mouse makes it barely move.
If I remove the `onScroll` event I can scroll horizontally normally again.

How can I scroll normally with the event?

**Listener**

```
document.getElementById('schedule-container').addEventListener('scroll', ctrl.onScroll, {capture: true, passive: true});
document.getElementById('shifts-container').addEventListener('scroll', ctrl.onScroll, {capture: true, passive: true});
```

**Handler**

```
ctrl.onScroll = e => {
    $('#schedule-container, #shifts-container').scrollLeft(e.target.scrollLeft);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want the one you manually scroll to change the other, you only want to apply `scrollLeft` to the other one and not the one you are working with

Try

```
$('#schedule-container, #shifts-container').not(e.target).scrollLeft(e.target.scrollLeft);
```